# Installing TL using ISO leads to local/unknown repository/tlpdb

Tags: texlive, installing

My setup at work did not allow me to install the latest TeX Live via [the net installer](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html). Instead, I downloaded the [huge ISO](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-iso.html), mounted it to some unused drive, and installed it from there without adding any options.

After installation, I unmounted the ISO drive and performed a package update via the command line

```
tlmgr update --self --all --reinstall-forcibly-removed
```

to see if there are any software/package updates. However, I received the error message that pointed to the original mounted location for the ISO, stating

```
Cannot determine type of tlpdb from R:!
tlmgr.pl: Cannot load TeX Live database from R:
```

(where `R:` was the original drive I mounted the ISO to).

How do I maintain/update my distribution in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install TeX Live, you can add options to `install-tl`, one of which is the repository from which to download packages/updates. Since you're using a local installation (a huge ISO), the default for TeX Live here is to specify a local repository that points to the drive letter where you mounted the ISO. Subsequent attempts at updating will also point to this, unless it's changed.

To change this after installation, you can call `tlmgr` with an optional `-repository <URL/path>` option (typically `<URL/path>` should point to the mirror `http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet`). However, this is only a *temporary* change for that specific run of `tlmgr`.

For a *permanent* update that will be stored inside the TeX Live Package Database (`tlpkg/tlmgr.tlpdb`), use the [`option repository`](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#option) option

```
tlmgr option repository http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet
```

after which you can update in the regular way:

```
tlmgr update --self --all --reinstall-forcibly-removed
```

---

If the above doesn't work (for whatever reason), you can open `tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb` and find the entry starting with

```
depend opt_location:
```

(usually at the top under `category TLCore`). This identifies the location of the repository. Change it to an online repository mirror, that is,

```
depend opt_location:http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet
```

and rerun your update; peace will be restored.

Comment: Trick `tlmgr option repository ctan` is the same as specifying the mirror url above